# Why does the minimum permission for read only access to an ms access database not mention about any permission requirement on the .laccdb (lock file)?

Tags: ms-access

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/lock-files-introduction#required-folder-privileges

> If you plan to share a database, the database file should be located
> in a folder where users have read, write, create, and delete
> privileges. Even if you want users to have different file privileges
> (for example, some read-only and some read-write), all users sharing a
> database must have read, write, and create permissions to the folder.
> You can, however, assign read-only permissions to the .accdb or .mdb
> file for individual users while still allowing full permissions to the
> folder.

For the purpose of this questions, assume that we have given the minimum folder permissions for a user (say **User2**) to have read only access to an access database. As per the above quote, the minimum permission is **read, write, and create at the folder level only [no flowing of this permission to the files in the folder]. And read permission at the access file (.accdb) level.**

1. Why is create permission mentioned? Marking read/write automatically allows user to create files in the folder - so why is create mentioned specifically?
2. Under which user account is the .laccdb (lock file) created?
3. In the following scenario: Say User1 with full folder level permissions has opened the access file. This will auto create the lock file. Now User2 open the access file (note this file is already opened on User1's PC). Now the User2 does not have any permission on the lock file. Is this permissible in read only access?

Comment: Users must be able to create, maintain, and delete the lock file, thus - apart from admin rights - have full access to the folder.

Comment: The msdn link is not clear in the sense that it only says FOLDER PERMISSION, doesnt say anything about inheriting that for the lock file

Comment: I guess that is because the user shouldn't bother. He/she, not even an admin, will never have to deal with that file.

Comment: But for example - if the user is assigned read/write permission to the folder only; and the user is assigned read only permission to the access database file; and the permission is not inherited by the files in the folder (due to company security policy), then the lock file will never get created, and user can never use the access db in shared mode.

Comment: True. That's why users need create and delete rights as well.

Comment: Folder level read/write includes create/delete of files implicitly, but if this folder permission (read/write) doesn't flow into the files in the folder (the lock file specifically) then it is of no use because the user will never be able to create the lock file. All I am saying is MSDN should specify that the permissions recommended are not only for FOLDER but should flow into files in the folder as well. Is my point making sense?

Comment: Not on an SMB share (Windows Server). Follow the Docs, and it will work.

Comment: I tried this - assigned user read/write on the FOLDER via the security tab (advanced - apply to folder only [so it wont flow into the files]). And then assigned read permission at accdb file. When user opened the access file (accdb), it didnt produce the lock file (obviously because read/write was only assigned at folder level - and specifically set to not flow into files in the folder) thus opening it in readonly mode. Hence this question.

Comment: OK, but as you have seen, you miss the third, Editing (localised) =Create/Delete.

Comment: Do you mean assigning "Editing (localised) =Create/Delete" on the lock file? Please can you clarify where is this to be done. I'm confused because the lock file doesn't exist when access db is closed. And doesn't read/write implicitly include create? Delete is not important for read only users as per that MSDN link so lets skip delete for now.

Comment: I believe the issue is that read/write in some cases does not always mean create rights. They "most likely" do, but then again - it not important. The bottom line is that create rights are required for read/write operations. The fact that read/write might, or might not result in create rights is never addressed in that statement and is moot point. The only thing we know and the ONLY claim noted here is that users need create rights. If read/write gets you that, then all fine and dandy - but you still need create rights. As noted, I believe that you can give read/write without create rights.

Comment: I agree to your point. But I am surprised that Microsoft document says permission to be given only at folder level. They are assuming that it will flow into the files especially the lock file. They should specifically say this. Otherwise when I restrict the permission to Folder only and if someone has opened the access file (thus creating a lock file) I will not have any permission on lock file. I hope you are getting my point.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, that the lock file isn't there, thus permissions must be set on the folder to allow for both the initial creating of the file (by the first user), the subsequent reading and writing as users come and go, and the final deleting (by the last user).

To achieve this, allow at least *Modify, Read & Execute, Read, Write*:

[image]

Also, don't forget the share permissions. These you will typically set to *Full Control*.